# Docker compose common config between services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to have a common configuration for all of my images. The solution that I found was to create a common service and extend it. My `docker-compose.yaml` file looks like this:

```
services:
  base:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    restart: always
    build:
      additional_contexts:
        some_context: ../../some_context
  service-a:
    extends:
      service: base
    build:
      context: ../service-a
  service-b:
    extends:
      service: base
    build:
      context: ../service-b
```

I can run `docker compose up [service]` if I want to run one service or `docker compose up service-a service-b` if I want to run both but running `docker compose up` fails because it does not find the dockerfile for service `base`.

```
failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: 
open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount457084940/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Is there any way to have a common config so that I am able to run `docker compose up` without naming any service?